# Naive parallelization of scipy.optimize.fmin

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, multiprocessing

The function [`scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs.html) allows the user to input both a target function and a gradient. Since I have an 8-core machine on my desktop, I thought I could parallelize the solver by running

```
from scipy import optimize
import itertools
import numpy as np

def single_grad_point((idx,px)):
    p = px.copy()
    epsilon = 10**(-6.0)
    p[idx] += epsilon
    d1 = err_func(p)
    p[idx] -= 2*epsilon
    d2 = err_func(p)
    return (d1-d2)/(2*epsilon)

def err_func_gradient(p):
    P = multiprocessing.Pool()   
    input_args = zip(*(xrange(len(p)), itertools.cycle((p,))))
    sol = P.imap(single_grad_point, input_args)
    return np.array(list(sol))

optimize.fmin_bfgs(err_func, p0, fprime=err_func_gradient)
```

In a nutshell, I'm using multiprocessing to compute each direction of the gradient. If the target function `err_func` is expensive, this seems to gain substantial speedup. My question however is about the usage and con/destruction of all the `multiprocessing.Pools`. Since it's possible that `err_func_gradient` can be called tens of thousands of times, **will this cause a slowdown or leak somewhere**?

Comment: I've looked, but scipy does not seem to have a parallel non-linear optimizer. If I'm wrong, I'll take it as an answer instead.

Comment: Could you not create your `multiprocessing.Pool` once, then pass it as an additional argument to `f` and `fprime`? That way you could perhaps avoid the overhead involved with constructing/destroying pools on every iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `mystic`, which provides parallel versions of a few of the `scipy.optimize` algorithms, including `fmin` and friends.

Trying to do a naive call to have each of the simplex evaluated in parallel is usually going to slow you down, unless you have some very very expensive objective functions to calculate.  However, if you instead call several instances of `fmin`, you can actually get pseduo-GLOBAL optimization at steepest-descent speeds.  The following example demonstrates an algorithm that has been used in several pubs (see below):
https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/master/examples/buckshot_example06.py

Or similarly, look at the examples here: using a fork of `multiprocessing`: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/examples2/optimize_cheby_powell_mpmap.py

or a fork of `parallelpython` (distributed parallel computing):
https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/examples2/optimize_cheby_powell_ppmap.py

or using an extension of `mpi4py`:
https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/examples2/optimize_cheby_powell_mpimap.py

Get `mystic` (the solver framework) and `pathos` (the parallel computing framework) here:
https://github.com/uqfoundation

Pub references (both slightly out of date):
http://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/scipy2011/mckerns.html
http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/mystic/wiki/Publications

If, however, you wanted to do the more naive version of `fmin`, the best approach is to only initialize and load the `pool` once.  This is what `pathos` provides for you already, but if you wanted to code it yourself, just save the instance of the `pool` as a singleton.
https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/pathos/multiprocessing.py

Comment: I can't find any reference on `mystic` regarding parallelized versions: http://pydoc.net/Python/mystic/0.2a1/mystic.scipy_optimize/. Just using `scipy_optimize.fmin` does not immediately lead to multiple processes in the solver.

Comment: Several examples exist in the github repositories, specifically this one: https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/master/examples/buckshot_example06.py  Note that all is needed is to use `solver.SetMapper`.  Or if you are using a population-based solver, then you can parallelize each generation -- but the latter typically works well only when the objective is very expensive.

Comment: None of those work for me, probably because I'm not installing mystic correctly. I don't want to derail this answer, but perhaps you could have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455709/mystic-version-lacks-many-features-from-the-git-repository

Comment: The release you are using is old.

Answer (score -3):

For starters, you can calc the gradient as

(f(x)-f(x+eps))/eps

Then calc f(x) once for all partial derivatives. That should save you half the work