# Mystic version lacks many features from the git repository?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I installed the current `pip` package of `mystic`, which has version

```
>>> mystic.__version__
Out[9]: '0.2a1'
```

, the current stable version. However, many features from the examples are missing. Take for example [this one](https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/master/examples/buckshot_example06.py), it uses

```
from mystic.solvers import BuckshotSolver
from mystic.pools import SerialPool as Pool
```

however my installation has neither `solvers` nor `pools`:

```
>>> from mystic import solvers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-11-5babfa66b1af>", line 1, in <module>
    from mystic import solvers
ImportError: cannot import name solvers
```

What am I missing? I tried installing both via `pip`, and via `conda skeleton pypi`, both to no avail.

Comment: Try using the instructions [here](http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/mystic/wiki/Installation) instead of using `pip`.

Comment: @AlexHall If you mean the tarball, that did not help either.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author.  The issue is that the latest stable release is old -- very old.  It's several years stale.  Don't use it.  Ok, so that's embarrassing… but for whatever reason, I haven't released `mystic` in a couple years. Development has been very steady over the past few years, and there has been a lot of growth in the package -- just no release.  So, obviously that needs to be corrected.  It's just been one of those things that keeps getting put on next week's pile of things to do.  So… you'll have to install from the git repository until I can get a new stable release together.

Something like this might work:

```
pip-2.7 install --target=test git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic.git@master
```

For full instructions, see here:
https://github.com/mmckerns/tutmom

The biggest issue is the version number is no longer supported as a valid format, so you need to install it as a "pre-release".  See discussion here (for a related issue):

https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/2

You should open a similar ticket for `mystic`.

---

**UPDATE:**
`mystic` now has a new release, so you can use `pip` as expected.

Comment: Mr. McKerns, 
Could you please suggest what is the current situation with mystic stable release? Where is it possible to find a version allowing to run all code which you showed in "Modern Optimization Methods in Python"  presentation  https://www.euroscipy.org/2015/schedule/presentation/51/? The latest available mystic version on the official site is 0.2a1 doesn't have necessary features.

Comment: Download it here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic, or install it as noted above in the answer.  I will be cutting a new stable release next month.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried two links and both of them have some problem. E.g. the "official" version from github.com/uqfoundation/mystic doesn't have all modules and reports an error during importing (_ImportError: No module named math.measures_). It seems we need to wait the next month stable release

Comment: The version on github works and is updated regularly -- and it has everything, so if for some reason it is not working for you, please fill out an issue on github, and we will figure it out.  No need to wait.